# IOS Admob implementation not showing banner ads on all devices

Tags: ios, admob, banner-ads

I released an app to the Apple app store. Previously, the google admob adds were appearing when I entered test devices. The ads used to appear with "test ad" text on top. However, after removing that and releasing the app I am not able to see any ads on some device. I am using banner ads.

I ran the app on Iphone 5, 5s, 6, 6s, 7, 8 Plus and X. The ads only appeared on 5s and 6s devices, not the rest. Any ideas why this is happening? Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ads started appearing on all devices after 5 days of the app release without me taking any action. It looks like there is some kind of delay. I emailed Google support but I haven't received a response yet.